# Getting Undefined for Radio Button Selection via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value from a user's choice of one of three radio buttons. So far my value returns `undefined` and I'm not clear why.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">
  <div class="well">
    <label>Repetition Interval</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="daily">
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Daily</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="weekly">
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Weekly</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="monthly">
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Monthly</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery I'm using to try and capture the value:

```
$("#step1").change(function () {
  const intervalValue = $("input[class='time-interval']:checked").val();
  console.log('intervalValue: ', intervalValue);
});
```

Right now the function does fire when a radio-button from the HTML block is selected, but, as I say, the value is `undefined`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the event like this:

```js
$("[type=radio]").change(function () {
  const intervalValue = this.value;
  console.log('intervalValue: ', intervalValue);
  console.log('name:', this.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">
  <div class="well">
    <label>Repetition Interval</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="daily">
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Daily</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="weekly">
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Weekly</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input interval" name="monthly">
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Monthly</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$("#step1").change(...)`: You are trying to caugh the event `onchange` on the `<div>`. So you may want to change it to the `<input>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some update.

```
1. Added unique name attribute for input
2. Added value attribute for input
3. Changed the selector for value select.
```

Hope this fits your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#step1').change(function() {
    const intervalValue = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    console.log('intervalValue: ', intervalValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">
  <div class="well">
    <label>Repetition Interval</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input
        type="radio"
        class="form-check-input time-interval"
        name="interval"
        value="daily"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Daily</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input
        type="radio"
        class="form-check-input time-interval"
        name="interval"
        value="weekly"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked"
        >Weekly</label
      >
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input
        type="radio"
        class="form-check-input time-interval"
        name="interval"
        value="monthly"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked"
        >Monthly</label
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 $(".form-check-input").change(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
 });
```

```html
<label>Repetition Interval</label>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input time-interval" value="daily" name="time_interval">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Daily</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input time-interval" value="weekly" name="time_interval">
    <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Weekly</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input time-interval" value="monthly" name="time_interval">
    <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Monthly</label>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyX8n.png)